# how to make POST request in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, sharepoint

im trying to create a post request to collect date from web site 
my request should be like this :

```
POST /api/recent HTTP/1.1 
Host: domain.org 
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
api_token=YOUR_TOKEN_VALUE
```

i trying this 0 error but is not working :

```
private const string URL = " MY url";
private const string Parameters = "api_key= my key";
public static string HttpPost(string URI, string Parameters)
{
    System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);


    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.Method = "POST";

    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Parameters);
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); //Push it out there
    os.Close();
    System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    if (resp == null) return null;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr =
          new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    return sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `class HttpClient`.

Comment: How does the data look like? What is on the request side, how do responses look? Did you verify a working endpoint, e.g. using Postman?

Comment: the data is look like 

{"message":"2 record(s) found","stixdocs":[{"id":"<ID>","title":"<TITLE>","xml":"<XML>", "created_at":"<DATETIME>","updated_at":
"<DATETIME>"} , {"id":"<ID>","title":"<TITLE>","xml":"<XML>", "created_at":"<DATETIME>","updated_at":"<DATETIME>"}]}

Comment: `but is not working` Define `not working`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your POST requests using [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)

Source code and some tutorials available on [GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki), tons of questions [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restsharp)